# EGit - Push to multiple remotes using ssh

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am trying to set up multiple remotes (on two different github accounts) in the EGit Eclipse plugin (I'm using Eclipse Photon 4.8.0) and push to them using SSH. OS is Windows 10.

As github does not allow to use the same SSH key multiple times, i generated two keys and added them to their respective accounts, and also in the SSH2 config in eclipse preferences under "Private keys:".

But I cannot seem to get both to work at the same time. If i delete all SSH config and remotes, restart, and set up the config for the account I want to push to, both work. So it is not an issue with the general configation.
However if I add both keys, and create both remotes, only the first one works, while the other one fails to connect when I try to push..

I'm not surprised it doesn't work, as I cannot find any way to specify which remote should use which ssh key, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have multiple SSH keys working. However, I had similar problems with EGit 5.0 (which is contained in Eclipse Photon) which were fixed by an upgrade. The current version is Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9) which contains EGit 5.1. Via the update site `http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates` you can already get EGit 5.1.2. Can you reproduce this issue with EGit 5.1.2?

Comment: I installed Eclipse 4.9 now, still same issue. I first added one key & remote, tried to push and it worked. I then restarted, added the second key and remote, restarted again, and tried to push to the second remote.. but now eclipse only asked me to enter the passphrase for the first key I added.. and unsurprisingly then fails to connect.. which again brings up my same question, is there no way to assign keys to specific remotes?
I suppose can try later if it works for keys without passphrase.

Comment: I have keys without passphrases but different accounts (e-mail addresses) and no [`.ssh/config` file](https://superuser.com/a/232406).

Comment: I did a test now using keys both without passphrase, still the same issue.
If i change the order the keys are listed under "Private keys:" in the SSH2 settings in preferences, and then restart eclipse, then the other key will work. But never both work at the same time.. ?